# Suppress Errors in readarray Command in Bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, jq

I'm parsing AWS policy documents and I'm trying to send the errors in this command to /dev/null so that the user doesn't see them.

This is my code:

```
readarray -t aws_policy_effects < \
    <( if aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn "$aws_policy_arn" \
              --version-id "$aws_policy_version_id"  --profile="$aws_key" 2> /dev/null | \
          jq -r '.PolicyVersion.Document.Statement[].Effect'
       then
           true
       else
           aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn "$aws_policy_arn" \
                   --version-id "$aws_policy_version_id" --profile="$aws_key" | \
               jq -r '.PolicyVersion.Document.Statement.Effect'
          fi)
```

I'm using an 'if' statement so that the right jq query gets used based on the aws policy that we're reading.

I will get this error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:22): Cannot index string with string "Effect"
```

Because this command always run as the first condition of the if (if there's no list the statement of the AWS policy document):

```
++ jq -r '.PolicyVersion.Document.Statement[].Effect'
++ aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789101:policy/IP_RESTRICTION --version-id v11 --profile=company-lab
```

Why isn't the error being buried by sending it to /dev/null? How can I get the error to not print out to the screen using this if statement?

Comment: You didn't redirect `jq`'s standard error, only the standard error of `aws`.

Comment: If you want to discard *all* error messages, just move the `2> /dev/null` to the end of the `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks! Putting the `2> /dev/null` to the end of the jq command works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using an 'if' statement so that the right jq query gets used based on the aws policy that we're reading.

But jq is telling you that your jq query is not always valid.  So one option would be to make your jq query more robust, e.g. by using postfix `?` (e.g. `.Effect?`), or testing the type of the input, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't redirect jq's standard error, only the standard error of aws. Putting the `2> /dev/null` to the end of the jq command works.